# Apply different calculations by row in r

Tags: parsing, eval, rowwise, expr

I am trying to calculate results per each row in a data frame
[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXuAv.png)

I have tried the following

`results$index<-noquote(results$Expr)`
`results$index<-parse(text=results$index)`
`results$index<-eval(results$index)`

`results %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(eval(eval(parse(text=noquote(index)))))`
`results %>% rowwise() %>%mutate(res = eval(rlang::parse_expr(character(index))))`

Answer (score 0):

This works

for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
results$index[which(results$indicator==i)]<-eval(rlang::parse_expr(results$expr[i]))
}

but it is taking a lot time